# Checkbox binding in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

OK so I have this checkbox in the view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsInvestment" @(Model.IsInvestment ? "checked value=true" : "value=false") />
```

which binds to

```
public Bool IsInvestment { get; set;}
```

It won't bind, unless I put this in the JS:

```
 $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).is(":checked"));
 });
```

Basically, I am writing "true" or "false" in the value of the input type checkbox each time the input is checked/unchecked.

P.S. It is a material checkbox

I don't remember doing this in the past, when I've used Html.CheckboxFor .....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you used `Html.CheckboxFor`, it didn't use the `value` attribute. It used the `checked` attribute to determine whether the value of the bound property was true or false.

Comment: I still have the checked attribute, but without value=true or value=false it won't bind. Very peculiar!

Comment: "it won't bind" is unclear. What's also unclear is why you don't just use `Html.CheckboxFor`, which would ensure the binding works for you.

Comment: It won't bind = even if the checkbox is checked, in the model it comes as false. (dooh)

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsInvestment" @(IsInvestment==true ? "checked": "") />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not enough, I tried only with the checked and it doesn't work. It wants value="true" explicitly. I believe it is because it's a checkbox from Materialize framework (it is the same for bootstrap checkbox I guess)